# Online file storage logic

Tags: php, file-manager

I want to develop a website like file manager. Where user register and will get fix disk space lets say 20MB.
Now user can upload their pdf, doc, txt, jpeg etc files upto their disk limit.
I can develop upto this using PHP.

Now below is my issue:

1) If user's files are corrupted they can rollback their folders before 2-3 days.
Files must be secure and safe from viruses as users are uploading their important documents.

Is there any 3rd party storage server who provides such facility?

2) Also all files should be previewed from browser.
I am using Google doc viewer. Is is good and safe way to preview file in browser?
But google links are accessible from all, I need to add some restrictions as file can be viewed only by their owner.

I know it's a major task, but i just need some sort of logic. Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Sounds like you need a source control system(checout svn or github, there are 3rd party providers)

2) You can restrict access in the gdocs interface, not sure if you can do it programmatically through the api though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Any cloud storage service can be used for this. You'll get HDD space. There is not storage server who provides revision control system for this. You can use git, svn for this though. But as the files are binary you can not get full facility of these tools.
2. How file will be previewed depends on you. If you use PHP you make the site and at the backend you use the API to interact with the storage service. Google doc is not an option for this if you use PHP. Also note Google links can be made private.

I suggest you this,

- Find a cloud storage service and use the storage in your server. Any will do.
- Create UI using PHP and control the access using PHP too.
- Manipulate files in your server directly or in 3rd party  storage server via API
- Use a revision control system to track the changes. And use its API in PHP end.

Some cloud storage service

1. [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). It also supports Versioning.
2. [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/)
3. [Microsoft Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/default.aspx)

Comment: Thanks shiplu. I got the point of 3rd party server. I am new to server providers. Will you suggest any cloud storage server personally? Also if i am using cloud how will i show preview of file in browser?

Comment: @VibhaJadwani using their API. Every provider have APIs

Comment: @VibhaJadwani I have included some links for you. I think you should give a try on Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft SkyDrive or Google Drive or Dropbox

Comment: Thanks.. I will check both. Do they provide API? I am using PHP and once user upload file on my site i will need to upload that file to SkyDrive or dropbox using PHP.

Comment: Yes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx https://developers.google.com/drive/ https://www.dropbox.com/developers Al if the cloud storage I mentioned provides roll back to old files, and API. Google Drive and Microsoft SkyDrive provides online document viewer.